# Mac OS X app - deploying to Applications directory

Tags: xcode, macos, deployment, installation, packaging

I'm trying to have my app deploy to a user's applications directory on install, but am having trouble determining the correct configuration settings.

Right now I have:

`Deployment Postprocessing - YES
Installation Build Products Location - ""
Installation Directory - "/Applications"`

This seems to work when doing `xcodebuild install`, but is this the best way to do this?  I had to change Installation Build Products Location from `/tmp/Project.dst` to an empty string which doesn't seem right.  Also should these settings be set on the target, the project, or both?

Comment: The assets do not show up in the Applications directory so I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

These settings seem to work fine. They should be set at the project level, not the target.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of DSTROOT (Installation Build Products Location) says:

> The path at which all products will be rooted when performing an
>   install build. For instance, to install your products on the system
>   proper, set this path to `/`. Defaults to `/tmp/$(PROJECT_NAME).dst`
>   to prevent a *test* install build from accidentally overwriting valid
>   and needed data in the ultimate install path. Typically this path is
>   not set per target, but is provided as an option on the command line
>   when performing an `xcodebuild install`. It may also be set in a build
>   configuration in special circumstances.

So the "official" way of doing it would be setting it to "/".